# Implement a Clock Divider for the Output SPI frequency to be 1MHz

Tags: verilog

I have written the following code for SPI Master, I want the SPI output frequecy to be 1MHz. Any suggestions how should I implement that. Thanks!

```
module spi_master(
    input wire clk,
    input wire reset,

    input wire [15:0] datain,

    output wire spi_cs_l,
    output wire spi_sclk,
    output wire spi_data,
    output wire [4:0] counter
);

reg [15:0] MOSI;
reg [4:0] count;
reg cs_l;
reg sclk;
reg [2:0] state;

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if(reset) begin
        MOSI <= 16'b0;
        count <= 5'd16;
        cs_l <= 1'b1;
        sclk <= 1'b0;
    end
    else begin
        case (state)
        0:begin
            sclk <= 1'b0;
            cs_l <= 1'b1;
            state <= 1;
        end
        1:begin
            sclk <= 1'b0;
            cs_l <= 1'b0;
            MOSI <= datain[count-1];
            count <= count-1;
            #50 state <= 2;
        end
        2:begin
            sclk <= 1'b1;
            if(count > 0) begin
                #50 state <= 1;
            end
            else begin
                count <= 16;
                state <= 0;
            end
        end
        default:state<=0;
        endcase
    end
end

assign spi_cs_l = cs_l;
assign spi_sclk = sclk;
assign spi_data = MOSI;
assign counter = count;

endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module spi_master_tb;

// Inputs

reg clk;
reg reset;
reg [15:0] datain;

// Outputs

wire spi_cs_l;
wire spi_sclk;
wire spi_data;
wire [4:0] counter;


spi_master dut(
    .clk(clk),
    .reset(reset),
    .counter(counter),
    .datain(datain),
    .spi_cs_l(spi_cs_l),
    .spi_sclk(spi_sclk),
    .spi_data(spi_data)
);


initial begin
    clk = 0;
    reset = 1;
    datain = 0;
end

always #5 clk=~clk;

initial begin
    #10 reset = 1'b0;

    #10 datain = 16'hA569;
    #335 datain = 16'h2563;
    #335 datain = 16'h9B63;
    #335 datain = 16'h6A61;

end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the `timescale` to be of `1ns/1ps`. With that the `clk` is running at 100MHz, to obtain 1MHz you need to see if your FSM is able to divide the `clk` by 100. Here it looks like that the `clk` is getting divided by 2 only.

See below code, here the `sclk` generation is kept outside the FSM.

```
module spi_master(
    input wire clk,
    input wire reset,

    input wire [15:0] datain,

    output wire spi_cs_l,
    output wire spi_sclk,
    output wire spi_data,
    output wire [4:0] counter
);

reg [15:0] MOSI;
reg [4:0] count;
reg [5:0] clk_count;
reg cs_l;
reg sclk;
reg [2:0] state;

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if(reset) begin
        MOSI <= 16'b0;
        count <= 5'd16;
        cs_l <= 1'b1;
    end
    else begin
        case (state)
        0:begin
            sclk <= 1'b0;
            cs_l <= 1'b1;
            state <= 1;
        end
        1:begin
            
            cs_l <= 1'b0;
            MOSI <= datain[count-1];
            count <= count-1;
            state <= 2;
        end
        2:begin
            
            if(count > 0) begin
                state <= 1;
            end
            else begin
                count <= 16;
                state <= 0;
            end
        end
        default:state<=0;
        endcase
    end
end

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) 
begin
  if(reset) 
  begin
   sclk <= 1'd0;
   clk_count <= 'd0;
  end
  else 
  begin
   sclk <= (clk_count == 'd49) ? ~sclk : sclk;
   clk_count <= (clk_count == 'd49) ? 'd0 : clk_count + 1'd1;
  end
 end

assign spi_cs_l = cs_l;
assign spi_sclk = sclk;
assign spi_data = MOSI;
assign counter = count;

endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you please let me know how to add the delay?

Comment: I delayed it by 100ns, but still getting output frequecy spi_sclk = 5MHz

Comment: I have edited my code above